# Grouping same xml elements using XSLT 2

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an **xml** document having same element repeated. I need to bring the adjacent div elements inside another element. Below my xml document contains p and div elements. All the div element should be **grouped inside the division**. If it is single or with adjacent.

```
   <doc>
    <section>
        <p class="h1">the fisr A</p>
        <p class="txt">one</p>
        <p>tow</p>
        <div>the sec B</div>
        <div>theree</div>
        <div>theree</div>
        <p class="h2">the sec sec B</p>
        <p class="txt">the next text</p>
        <p class="h3">the fisr C</p>
        <p class="txt">four</p>
        <div>five</div>
        <div>the seccond A</div>
        <p class="txt">the seccond txt</p>
        <p class="h2">the second B</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p class="txt">six</p>
        <div>seven</div>
        <p class="txt">eight</p>
        <p class="txt">nine</p>
    </section>
</doc>
```

I need to bring the adjacent div elements in one parent element division. Below is my output.

```
   <doc>
    <section>
        <p class="h1">the fisr A</p>
        <p class="txt">one</p>
        <p>tow</p>
        <division>
            <div>the sec B</div>
            <div>theree</div>
            <div>theree</div>
        </division>
        <p class="h2">the sec sec B</p>
        <p class="txt">the next text</p>
        <p class="h3">the fisr C</p>
        <p class="txt">four</p>
        <division>
            <div>five</div>
            <div>the seccond A</div>
        </division>
        <p class="txt">the seccond txt</p>
        <p class="h2">the second B</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p class="txt">six</p>
        <division>
            <div>seven</div>
        </division>
        <p class="txt">eight</p>
        <p class="txt">nine</p>
    </section>
</doc>
```

I have tried the below xslt.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="div" group-adjacent="div">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
            <division>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </division>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please someone try to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a template matching `body` but there are no `body` elements in your XML. You probably meant `section` here.

For the grouping, you should really be selecting all elements, not just div, and then for the group-adjacent you need an expression that returns true if it the element is a div, or false otherwise.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::div)">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
            <division>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </division>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```